# py.test could not collect the tests due to the Syntax Error at File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jsondiff/__init__.py", line 367

Tags: python, pytest

I am running few tests which are unittest module, and it refers jsondiff module.
When i run the tests py.test it reurning me below error. What is this mean?

I tried re-installing jsondiff but could not resolve.
Could someone help out.

```
py.test /root/git/automation/PythonAPI/SDSN/PolicyAnalysis/PA.py
======================================================================= test session starts =======================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.6.6, pytest-3.0.0, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /root/git/automation/PythonAPI, inifile: setup.cfg
plugins: html-1.10.0
collected 0 items / 1 errors

============================================================================= ERRORS ==============================================================================
___________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting SDSN/PolicyAnalysis/PA.py ____________________________________________________________
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:410: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/py-1.4.31-py2.6.egg/py/_path/local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:207: in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
/root/git/automation/PythonAPI/SDSN/PolicyAnalysis/PA.py:14: in <module>
    from PolicyAnalysisUtils import PolicyAnalysisUtils
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:207: in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
/root/git/automation/PythonAPI/Common/PolicyAnalysisUtils.py:10: in <module>
    import jsondiff
E     File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jsondiff/__init__.py", line 367
E       for symbol in (add, discard, insert, delete, update)
E         ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you sure the module you're using is compatible with Python 2.6? Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: [Source](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/jsondiff/blob/master/jsondiff/__init__.py) uses dictionary comprehensions, which are available starting from Python 2.7. For new code bases, Python 3 is recommended.

Comment: Thanks, actually i was using python 2.6 which was available by default. after Installing Python2.7.8 it worked fine.